# Django i18n using translation.activate

Tags: django, internationalization, language-translation

I have configured Django i18n and it works just fine if you change the browser language using the browser configuration UI. I have tested both English and Spanish. However, when I try to let the user pick the language from the navigation bar and set a new LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY based on the selection made by the user it would not work. The browser language will continue to be the selected language instead.

Here follows my code:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
...

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
    ('pt', _('Portuguese'))
   
)
```

The view that is triggered by the navbar:

```
def setLanguage(request, language_code):
    language = get_language()
    
    try:
        request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = language_code
        translation.activate(language_code)
        request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()
        request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = language_code
        request.session.save()
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$  Oops!", e.__class__, "occurred.")
        translation.activate(language)
       
    return redirect('home_index')
```

I have debugged that the language_code passed corresponds correctly to the selected language (e.g. es instead of en) but it is not activated. The browser language remains as the active language.

I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks!
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that the locale middleware is causing this, so I just commented it out. It is working as expected now.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```